# Spring Boot Service Junit Mockito issue

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have written Junit for the service. mocking dao. 
Service method return type in EmployeeDTO.
Dao return type is Employee.
problem is employee to employeeDto conversion failed in test case.
when(dao.method()).thenReturn(new Employee), so on call od service.method() I am facing issue since dozer is in between to convert employee to employeedto in the actual code.
any suggestions to fix this.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { EmployeeSearchService.class, EmployeeDao.class })
public class EmployeeSearchServiceTest {

    @Mock // will create a mock implementation for the EmployeeDao
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @InjectMocks // will inject the mocks marked with @Mock to this instance when it is created.
    private EmployeeSearchService employeeSearchService ;

    @Mock
    private DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @DisplayName("fetchEmployees with valid data")
    @Test
    public void testfetchEmployeesWithValidData() throws IOException {

        when(employeeDao.fetchEmployees()).thenReturn(Stream
            .of(new Employee((long) 1, "James", "Java", "Manager", "Google"),
                    new Employee((long) 2, "Richard", "C++", "Manager", "Microsfot"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));


        //when(dozer.map(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(employeeDTO);
        System.out.println(employeeSearchService.fetchEmployees());
        assertEquals(4, employeeSearchService.fetchEmployees().size());
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class EmployeeSearchServiceImpl implements EmployeeSearchService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Autowired
    DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper;

    @Override
    @Logging
    public List<EmployeeDTO> fetchEmployees() throws IOException {

        List<Employee> aEmployeeList = employeeDao.fetchEmployees();
        List<EmployeeDTO> aEmployeeDTOList= aEmployeeList.stream().map(emp -> 
                                                      dozerBeanMapper.map(emp, 
                                     EmployeeDTO.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (aEmployeeList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmployeeNotfoundException("Employee Details Not Available");
        }
        return aEmployeeDTOList;
    }    
}
```

```java
@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao {

    @Override
    @Logging
    public List<Employee> fetchEmployees() throws IOException {

        List<String>  aFileList=fileUtils.getFileContent(EmployeeSearchConstants.EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_PATH);

        List<Employee> aEmployeList = getEmployee(aFileList);

        if (aEmployeList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmployeeNotfoundException("Employee Details Not Available");
        }

        return aEmployeList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you mock the `DozerBeanMapper` ?

Comment: In the Junit, Employee to Employee DTO conversion

Comment: @WimDeblauwe no thats nowhere used in the unittest. issue is service method return type is employee. and dao method return type is employeedto. when(dao.method()).thenReturn(new Employee). so on call of service.method() I have to get the emplyee dto . here in between I used dozer for that conversion

Comment: Hi, Rahiman. Could you post the error stack trace?

Comment: @SurajGautamjava.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.service.impl.EmployeeSearchServiceImpl.lambda$0(EmployeeSearchServiceImpl.java:62)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
 at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
 at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)

Comment: The exception should be caused by not defining behaviour for the `dozerBeanMapper.map` method. By default all methods of a mock return `null` or the primitve default value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your issue is that you are looking for a way to convert your `Employee` into a `EmployeeDTO` object, which in your code is done using `dozerBeanMapper.map(emp, EmployeeDTO.class)`.

---

One option would be to change the `EmployeeSearchServiceImpl` and use Constructor Injection instead of Field Injection. This way you could simply use the real dozer class to do the mapping  (by manually passing the mock for `employeeDao` and the real `dozerBeanMapper`).

Constructor Injection is done by moving the @Autowired to the constructor instead of the fields. Depening on your spring version and in case you only have one constructor for the class you might be able to omit the annotation.  For more information check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring).

```java
EmployeeDao employeeDao;
DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper;

@Autowired
public EmployeeSearchServiceImpl(EmployeeDao employeeDao, DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper) {
    this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
    this.dozerBeanMapper = dozerBeanMapper;
}
```

---

Another option would be to use Mockito's `thenAnser` functionality. However
you still require something to do the conversion for you.

```java
when(dozerBeanMapper.map(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<EmployeeDTO>() {
    public EmployeeDTO answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        Employee employee = (Employee) invocation.getArguments()[0];

        // convert to EmployeeDTO
        EmployeeDTO dto = ...
        return dto;
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide some more info regarding constructor injection for EmployeeSearchServiceImpl

Comment: I`ve added a small sample how your constructor should look like and linked a related tutorial containt some more basic informations.